# Add support for multiple results sets in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, multiple-results-sets

If you run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/q/17858/) in [Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) it would appear that both queries run since the message window reads...

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(555 row(s) affected)
```

...but only the first result is displayed or exported (download results).

It would be nice if all result sets where displayed and exported. Or at least exported.

If N number of result sets seems like asking for trouble, perhaps a limit > 1 would be acceptable.

Comment: Good idea. Given that you can run any number of query *windows* right now, it's probably fine to just limit the number of multi-results to something sane like 5. I doubt a lot of people will be using this.

Comment: If you choose results as text you will get both result sets

Comment: @waffles nice. not as a cool as if there was full support but since it's a bit of a corner case and probably not in high demand I would certainly accept it if it was given as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of [this fairly lengthy list of commits](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/47) is that you will now be able to get multiple result sets back and have them be rendered by Slick Grid, with the ability to toggle between them:

[image: result set toggle]

Per the pull request description, a number of related issues are fixed. This includes [unexpected triggering of the graphing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228519/graphing-lots-of-data-crashes-my-browser) crashing the browser tab, the grids having an inconsistent style from the rest of the site, and a problem with sorting magic columns (and not knowing that the columns were sortable in the first place).

Answer (score 2):

If you choose results as text you will get both result sets.

I am not against adding support for multiple grids. It is, however, a fairly complex change (contributions are welcome).