# Rounding issue on data explorer graphs

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, tooltips

Whenever a graph is created with Data Explorer using a query that returns non-integers, the tooltips which appear when hovering over the data points are rounded to integers.

This is a problem, for instance, when viewing a graph which only returns percentages in decimal form: (graph taken from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194620/accept-rate-by-rep?maxReputation=200#graph))

[image: A graph showing that when hovering over a data point which should be around 0.65, the tooltip reads 0]

Although the issue can be fixed with this particular query by scaling all the points vertically by a factor of 100, "hackish" methods like these evidently won't work for all queries that naturally return decimal numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this while [working on some other stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74289/add-support-for-multiple-results-sets-in-data-explorer/231514#231514) and it'll [now show two decimal places as appropriate](https://github.com/tms/StackExchange.DataExplorer/commit/f8864a1a331e4848a27af2f046e413ad5c657782) for values less than 1000 once that PR has been merged and Data Explorer redeployed.

So, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) preemptively.