# How can I export all results from a to multi-result-set-query to a CSV file?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, multiple-results-sets

In May 2014, the support was added to [download result sets from a SEDE query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74289/add-support-for-multiple-results-sets-in-data-explorer).

Today I used [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/270401#resultSets)

```
sp_help 'tagsynonyms'
```

which gives six result sets:

[image: SEDE Resultgrid 2 of 6]

I needed the second result off-line, so I clicked the *Download CSV* link. The CSV contained only the first (uninteresting) resultset.

Is there a possibility to use the *Download CSV* feature to get any of the other result-sets in a multi-result-set query? If this isn't possible, can this be implemented?

Until this is available, I use the text-result.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, I remember thinking in passing that the link should at least download the currently visible result set, but obviously I never actually implemented it that way.

So, currently there is no way to do this, but I'll make the above-described changes if that sounds acceptable.

Comment: That is would be great, let me change my post to a feature-request.